# ggplot stat_bin2d plot with heavily skewed data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data that is heavily right skewed.  This creates a problem when doing a stat_bin2d plot.  The result is most of the graph is dark blue with only a few points are a different color.  I'd like to have the graph use the entire color range a bit more.

An example of the problem is from the ggplot documentation direction.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + stat_bin2d()
```

The resulting graph has only a few positions that are something other than dark blue.

How can I adjust the mapping of the color range to show more detail?  I know I can set the limits, but this doesn't exactly fit the bill as it makes anything outside the limits be gray.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + stat_bin2d() + scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(1, 100))
```

Something like this with they gray appropriately colored too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick answer is

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + stat_bin2d() +
  scale_fill_gradient(trans="log10")
```

**EDIT:**
A longer answer is that you probably want some kind of transformation of the color or fill scale. For built-in transformations refer to the "See Also" section of

```
library(scales)
?trans
```

If none of the built-in transformation is suitable then you can construct your own. See the answers to [this SO question about transforming color scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186827/transform-color-scale-but-keep-a-nice-legend-with-ggplot2/12189857#12189857) for an example showing how to do this.

Comment: That works well for the example, but is there a more general purpose solution that can give me more control?  The trans doesn't work well with my specific data set.

Comment: @robbie I've updated the question with more general info about transformations. Since you haven't given an example of your actual problem I can't be more specific than this.

Comment: This is perfect!  The hardest part of finding the answer is knowing what to search for.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ista wonderful, your answer is quite good. Now I want to transform by dividing 1000 to make scientific notation transform, and I construct my own, `sci_trans <- function(){ trans_new('sci', function(x) x/1000, function(x) x*1000)}`  , `p + scale_fill_gradient(trans='sci')`. But it does not work, nothing has changed, what is wrong with my func? Thank you, Sir

Comment: @LingZhang If you still have questions about this please ask a new question.