# Transform color scale to probability-transformed color distribution with scale_fill_gradientn()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize heavily tailed raster data, and I would like a non-linear mapping of colors to the range of the values. There are a couple of similar questions, but they don't really solve my specific problem (see links below).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
   x = floor(runif(10000, min=1, max=100)),
   y = floor(runif(10000, min=2, max=1000)),
   z = rlnorm(10000, 1, 1) )

# colors for the colour scale:   
col.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan", "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))
fill.colors <- col.pal(64)
```

This is how the data look like if not transformed in some way:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
   geom_tile(width=2, height=30) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors)
```

[image]
My question is sort of a follow-up question related to 
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834802/non-linear-color-distribution-over-the-range-of-values-in-a-geom-raster) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299705/asymmetric-color-distribution-in-scale-gradient2) , and the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838299/5444561) actually yields exactly the plot I want, except for the legend:

```
qn <- rescale(quantile(dat$z, probs=seq(0, 1, length.out=length(fill.colors))))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
   geom_tile(width=2, height=30) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors, values = qn)
```

[image]

Now I want the colour scale in the legend to represent the non-linear distribution of the values (now only the red part of the scale is visible), i.e. the legend should as well be based on quantiles. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I thought the `trans` argument within the colour scale might do the trick, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186827/transform-color-scale-but-keep-a-nice-legend-with-ggplot2)  , but that throws an error, I think because `qnorm(pnorm(dat$z))` results in some infinite values (I don't completely understand the function though..).

```
norm_trans <- function(){
   trans_new('norm', function(x) pnorm(x), function(x) qnorm(x)) 
}
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
   geom_tile(width=2, height=30) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors, trans = 'norm')
> Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

So, does anybody know how to have a quantile-based colour distribution in the plot *and* in the legend?

Comment: why not just use `trans = "log"`? A normal transformation doesn't make much sense on lognormal data. And rainbow colour schemes are a really bad idea. #endrainbow

Comment: For this toy dataset, `trans="log"` would be fine, just for my specific data I would like a quantile distribution. And sorry for the rainbow scale (and thanks for pointing to the #endrainbow), I needed to be consistent with a specific convention...

Comment: Problem seems to be with labeling::extended, perhaps because pnorm is a poor fit to the data. Switching pnorm with plnorm makes the figure work. Alternatively, set the breaks manually.

Comment: Yes, plnorm would give a reasonable result; but what can I do if I really want a quantile transformation? As to setting the breaks manually (assuming you mean something like this `scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors, values=qn, breaks=c(0.01,1,10))`): this doesn't transform the colour scale in the legend, just labels at the specified values.

Comment: I don't see how to get the quantile transformation to work, because you also need the reverse transformation. I was meaning to use manual breaks with the pnorm transform, as the automatic breaks didn't work

Comment: Yes, exactly my problem.. How can I use manual breaks with pnorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will make manual breaks with a pnorm transformation. Is this what you are after?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile(width=2, height=30) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors, 
                       trans = 'norm', 
                       breaks = quantile(dat$z, probs = c(0, 0.25, 1))
  )
```

Comment: This throws an error - how did you define `norm_trans` ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault - too many norm_trans definitions, so no error any more.

Comment: The colour scale definitely looks good now; I just expected the colours in the plot to look exactly like my second example above, because both would be based on quantiles, but they don't. (More shifted to red in your example). But maybe I just don't understand pnorm and qnorm completely, so I guess yours is the best solution to the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have been looking for a quantile transform. Unfortunately there is none in `scales`, but it is not to hard to build one yourself (on the fly):

```r
make_quantile_trans <- function(x, format = scales::label_number()) {
  name <- paste0("quantiles_of_", deparse1(substitute(x)))
  xs <- sort(x)
  N <- length(xs)
  transform <- function(x) findInterval(x, xs)/N # find the last element that is smaller
  inverse <- function(q) xs[1+floor(q*(N-1))]

  scales::trans_new(
    name = name,
    transform = transform,
    inverse = inverse,
    breaks =  function(x, n = 5) inverse(scales::extended_breaks()(transform(x), n)),
    minor_breaks = function(x, n = 5) inverse(scales::regular_minor_breaks()(transform(x), n)),
    format = format,
    domain = xs[c(1, N)]
  )
}

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile(width=2, height=30) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=fill.colors, trans = make_quantile_trans(dat$z))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>