# Is it possible to pass additional parameters to trans_new of the scales package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a transformation for ggplot2 that scales the x axis to have a uniform visual distribution.

Following [this](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2012/08/14/custom-axis-transformations-in-ggplot2/) tutorial I did a naive implementation of the following:

```
q_trans <- function() trans_new(
  "quantile",
  transform = function(x, a) {mean (x >= a)},
  inverse   = function(x, a) {sort(a)[x*length(a)]}
)
```

But when I run

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_smooth() + coord_trans(x = "q")
```

I get the somewhat expected error

> Error in mean(x >= a): argument "a" is missing, with no default

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/scales.pdf) under `?trans_new` doesn't give any information if and how I can pass additional parameters to the transformation functions.
The [coord_trans](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_trans.html) documentation also doesn't seem to indicate the possibility to pass additional parameters.

---

For my purpose it would even be enough to be able to access the underlying sample.
Kind of how you can pass the array the element comes from when mapping in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or many other languages.
There you can do it simply by adding another parameter in the transformation function like I did above.

---

### Edit

Roman Luštrik's suggestion made me realize that transform is itself vectorized so I need to to the following assuming a is a global variable:

```
q_trans <- function() trans_new(
  "quantile",
  transform = function(x) {sapply(x, function(x_i){mean (x_i >= a)})},
  inverse   = function(x) {sapply(x, function(x_i){sort(a)[x_i*length(a)]})}
)
a <- mpg$displ
```

If I run `a <- mpg$displ` the call to ggplot2 works but it's not very elegant.

Comment: My call is correct for my version of ggplot2 `coord_trans(x = 'q_trans')` yields `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir): object 'q_trans_trans' of mode 'function' was not found`. The issue is that there is no definition for `a` which I would like to be the underlying population.

Comment: Have you tried passing `a` from global environment?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I can indeed get it to work like that, it just seems that this shouldn't be the only way.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38874741/1870254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `a` as an argument of your function.

```
q_trans <- function(a = NULL) trans_new(
    "quantile",
    transform = function(x) {sapply(x, function(x_i){mean (x_i >= a)})},
    inverse   = function(x) {sapply(x, function(x_i){sort(a)[x_i*length(a)]})}
)
```

Then use `q_trans` instead of `"q"` in `coord_trans`, passing whatever vector you want to use for `a`.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    coord_trans(x = q_trans(a = mpg$displ))
```