# "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when using scales::trans_new()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to write `scales::trans_new()` function to use in a map that will be produced by `ggplot2`. Nevertheless, it keeps firing this error:

```
Error in x^-0.275 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Example data:

```
# input 
x<-c("0.1300", "0.3700", "0.0800", "0.0800", "0.0500", "0.0800", 
         "0.1500", "0.1700", "0.2500", "0.0700", "0.1000", "1.1300", "0.1300", 
         "0.2500", "0.0800", "0.0800", "0.3100", "0.1300", "0.0400", "0.0800", 
         "0.1300", "0.1500", "0.2000", "1.0600", "0.2200", "0.1000", "0.1300", 
         "0.1200", "0.0400", "0.4500", "0.0900", "0.0900", "0.1600", "0.0300", 
         "0.2100", "0.1700", "0.3400", "0.4900", "0.0500", "0.1500", "0.1900", 
         "0.1700", "0.2300", "0.0600", "0.0500", "0.3800", "0.2700", "0.0900", 
         "0.0400", "0.0800", "0.1700", "0.2800", "0.0600", "0.0800", "0.0800", 
         "0.2300", "0.1000", "0.0800", "0.0900", "0.0700", "0.0500", "0.3500", 
         "0.2700", "0.1000", "0.1600", "0.0900", "0.0700", "0.1800", "0.1500", 
         "0.2300", "0.5200", "0.3400", "0.0800", "0.2400", "0.1300", "0.1500", 
         "0.4300", "0.0600", "0.0800", "0.1000", "0.0800", "0.1300", "0.2700", 
         "0.0500", "0.1600", "0.0900", "0.3300", "0.3600", "0.0600", "0.3500", 
         "0.0900", "0.1400", "0.1500", "0.1500", "0.4500", "0.1900", "0.2500", 
         "0.0300", "0.2000", "3.0200", "0.1800", "0.1400", "2.0300", "0.1100", 
         "0.1800", "0.2900", "0.1300", "0.1200", "0.1100", "0.1400", "0.1000", 
         "0.1600", "0.1100", "0.1000", "0.0700", "0.1000", "0.1000", "0.3800", 
         "0.0400", "0.1500", "0.0900", "0.1600", "0.0600", "0.4300", "0.3100", 
         "0.1600", "0.2400", "0.4100", "0.0700", "0.0500", "0.2100", "0.1200", 
         "0.1100", "0.4800", "0.1100", "0.0900", "0.1100", "0.0800", "0.4800", 
         "0.3300", "0.3700", "0.1600", "0.3800", "0.3200", "0.1600", "0.1800", 
         "0.4900", "0.1700", "0.3100", "0.1600")
```

Workflow:

```
# convert
x <- as.numeric(x)
# obtain transformation
lambda <- rcompanion::transformTukey(x, returnLambda = TRUE)

if (lambda > 0) {
  TRANS <- x^lambda
}
if (lambda == 0) {
  TRANS <- log(x)
}
if (lambda < 0) {
  TRANS <- -1 * x^lambda
}
# transform
trans_legendFUN <- function(x) {
  -1 * x^-0.275
}
# inverse transform
inverse_legendFUN <- function(y) {
  (-1 * y)^(1 / -0.275)
}
legendFUN <- scales::trans_new(
  name = "legendFUN",
  transform = trans_legendFUN,
  inverse = inverse_legendFUN
)
# plotting
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:15, y = 1:10)
df$value <- x
# plot setting
legend_title <- "legend_title"
bw <- seq.int(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)))
limits <- bw[c(1, length(bw))]
leg_colors <- colorRamps::matlab.like(length(bw))

ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::theme_void(base_size = 6) +
  ggplot2::geom_raster(
    data = df,
    mapping = ggplot2::aes(x, y, fill = value)
  ) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = leg_colors,
    limits = limits,
    breaks = scales::breaks_pretty,
    trans = legendFUN,
    oob = scales::squish,
    guide = ggplot2::guide_colourbar(
      direction = "horizontal",
      title.position = "bottom",
      title.hjust = .5,
      label.position = "top",
      ticks = F,
      title = legend_title
    )
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.key.width = ggplot2::unit(5.0, "mm"),
    legend.key.height = ggplot2::unit(1.5, "mm"),
    legend.margin = ggplot2::margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.box.margin = ggplot2::margin(0, 0, 0, 0)
  )
```

BTW: If I removed `limits` and `breaks` from `ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn()`, it produces the plot, but not the limits and breaks I would like to show. I also checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639622/13818750) from here, where I tried to provide lambda as a variable, not successful!

**EDIT:**
following stefan's recommendation, I changed the following:

```
# transform
trans_legendFUN <- function(x) {
  x<-ifelse(x<0.0001,0.0001,x)
  x<- -1 * x^-0.275
  return(x)
}
```

Adding transform function for labelling:

```
scaleFUN <- function(x) sprintf("%.0f", x)
```

Defining legend limits, starting with 0.1 to avoid error:

```
bw <- seq.int(0.1, 7)
```

Adapting the new scale/legend setup:

```
  ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = leg_colors,
    limits = limits,
    breaks = bw,
    trans = legendFUN,
    oob = scales::squish,
    labels = scaleFUN,
    guide = ggplot2::guide_colourbar(
      direction = "horizontal",
      title.position = "bottom",
      title.hjust = .5,
      label.position = "top",
      ticks = F,
      title = legend_title
    )
  )
```

And it worked:

[image]

Comment: Your x  vector (or value column) is a character. Try with `df$value <- as.numeric(x)`.

Comment: This is already done in the first two lines of the workflow!

Comment: Aw. Sorry. The issue is with `breaks = scales::pretty_breaks`. Use `breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()`instead. But be aware that you still get an error as the lower 0 limit gets transformed into `-Inf`. BTW: If you add code please format it as proper and runnable code instead of copying the outputted code from your console.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan for your hints! I think I found a way around! Using the outputted code was just to show the code is running! I agree with your point :)